# How to delay updating View elements inside a ForEach loop?

Tags: swiftui

I want to update an HStack of Text views, but I don't want each Text view to immediately, I want each Text view to update a half-second after the last one. The problem is that in using a Timer delay which would work for me in UIKit, it isn't working in SwiftUI, and I'm getting the following error inside the timer block:

Result of 'Text' initializer is unused

I understand what the error means, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The value of Text is inside the Timer block and the ForEach doesn't see the creation of the Text view.

Also, creating an HStack of Text views is not optimal, but this is just a test app I'm writing for something bigger, but the error will still happen since the view reference gets lost. This is the easiest example to show the error I want to fix.

```
class TextModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stringOfText: String = "Howdy"
}

struct MyCellEnv: View {
@ObservedObject var testText = TextModel()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {
            let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { timer in
                updateText()
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Action", systemImage: "chevron.right.circle")
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .padding()
        }
        let testTextArray = Array(testText.stringOfText)
        HStack {
            ForEach(testTextArray, id: \.self) { character in
                let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { timer in
                let _ = print(character)
                Text(String(character))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private func updateText() {
    testText.stringOfText = "Hello"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` of a SwiftUI view is there to describe how the current state of the view should be rendered on screen. You can't control how often or when the body is evaluated, so it isn't suitable for adding in logic statements in the way you have.

Your view body should be updated based on a display string `@State` property, which you can update via a timer or other mechanism. I'd suggest using a task modifier:

```swift
struct MyCellEnv: View {
    @StateObject var testText = TextModel()
    @State private var displayText = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                updateText()
            } label: {
                Label("Action", systemImage: "chevron.right.circle")
                    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .padding()
            }
            Text(displayText)
        }
        .task(id: testText.stringOfText) {
            let string = testText.stringOfText
            var index = 0
            let sequence = AsyncStream<String> {
                if index > string.count { return nil }
                do {
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
                } catch {
                    return nil
                }
                let part = String(string.prefix(index))
                index += 1
                return part
            }
            
            for await string in sequence {
                self.displayText = string
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    private func updateText() {
        testText.stringOfText = "Hello"
    }
}
```

- I made your model a `StateObject` since you are initialising it here which means this view owns the reference.
- I added a `State` variable to hold the text that should be displayed.
- I made a single `Text` to display the text
- I added a `task` modifier with an `id`, this will start (and cancel the old one) a new task when the view appears, and every time the value of `testText.stringOfText` is updated. It uses an `AsyncStream` to build up the display string.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I've been a Mac/(and later)iOS dev since 1989, but started SwiftUI about 4 hours before I made that post, so the change in logistics is a little new to me, but this made sense. This helped a lot!